# Reformulate a term

Tags: exponential-function

How did we got this?

We had to find $T$.

From:

$$\frac{R}{R_1}= e^{b(\frac{1}{T}-\frac{1}{T_0})}$$

This:

$$T= \frac{b T_0}{T_0\ln R-T_0\ln R_0+b}$$

Comment: What have you attempted? Specifically, taking the logarithm on both sides -- did you try that?

Comment: Of course I did, but after doing that I do not come to the formula.

Comment: See my answer, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take the logarithm on both sides:
   $$
   \ln R - \ln R_1 = b\left(\frac{1}{T}-\frac{1}{T_0}\right)
   $$
2. Divide both sides by $b\neq 0$ and add $\frac{1}{T_0}$:
   $$
   \frac{1}{b}\left( \ln R - \ln R_1\right) + \frac{1}{T_0} = \frac{1}{T}
   $$
3. Take the reciprocal of both sides:
   $$
   \frac{1}{\frac{1}{b}\left( \ln R - \ln R_1\right) + \frac{1}{T_0}} = T
   $$
4. Multiply both numerator and denominator of the LHS by $b$:
   $$
   \frac{b}{\ln R - \ln R_1 + \frac{b}{T_0}} = T
   $$
5. Multiply both numerator and denominator of the LHS by $T_0$:
   $$
   \frac{bT_0}{T_0\ln R - T_0\ln R_1 + b} = T
   $$

Comment: Incidentally, this is under the (implicit) assumption $b\neq 0$, and that the $R_0$ written in your question is actually a typo for $R_1$.

Comment: Thanks. But in the last step you have missed $bT_0$ in the numerator.

Comment: @Questionnaire Indeed, thank you. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{R}{R_1}= e^{b({\frac{1}{T}-\frac{1}{T_0})}}$
Take logarithm to the base $e$ on both sides. 
ln(R/R1)= b{(1/T)-(1/T0)}
{1/b}{ln R - lnR1}= {(1/T)-(1/T0)} 
(As ln (a/b)= ln a - ln b)
1/T = {T0(ln R - ln R1) - b}/{T0*b}
Reciprocal on both sides
T={T0*b}/{T0(ln R - ln R1) - b}

Comment: Sorry for Math formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Start of by taking the ln on both sides.
Note: that after you take the ln on both side
ln(e^x)=x: This is what you are missing.

$Ln(\frac{R}{R1})$=$b*(\frac{1}{T}-\frac{1}{T_0})$

then use properties of logs and algebra to simplify to whatever you need.